# Pytho2.7 как очистить Unicode строку от левых символов?

Tags: python, unicode

например у меня вот такая строка

```
desc=u"привет 123123123  тут какой то текст 12349! abcde 123"
```

частично решение я нашел:

```
re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]+',' ', desc)
```

или

```
"".join(filter(lambda x: ord(x)<128,desc.decode('utf-8')))
```

но проблема в том что удаляются все кириллические символы и получается:

```
 123123123      12349! abcde 123
```

а еще в строке может быть м², это же тоже получается спецсимвол. его я бы хотел оставить.

Comment: Этот символ, этот не хочу... Какие в итоге нужно оставить? Вам нужно формализовать требование и вопрос отпадет сам собой.

Comment: Почему вы не хотите дополнить регулярку кирилическими символами или не убираете только левые символы (вместо всех меньше 128)?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - решение в лоб, создайте список "правых" символов и <strike>убивайте</strike> удаляйте неверных!

Comment: это самый костыльный вариант :/

Comment: @JohnDoe, Он пока единственный. У создателей python не было такой проблемы.

Comment: я нашел решение. оно простое. и ненадо создавать бредовые списки нужных символов

Comment: @JohnDoe: чудес не бывает -- что такое "левый символ" ни в каком стандарте не прописано -- так или иначе вам придётся задавать диапазоны символов, которые вы хотите оставить (белый список) и символы, которые вы хотите исключить (чёрный список), например, вы можете хотеть [исключить emoji  символы](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33404752/4279) такой как [`` (U+1F646 FACE WITH OK GESTURE)](https://codepoints.net/U+1F646)

Comment: бывает.  конкретно в этом случае точно. те странные символы являются четырехбайтовым юникодом. мускул такое из коробки не умеет. и решается это заменой по вот такой регулярке re.compile(u'[\U00010000-\U0010ffff]')

Comment: кстати квадратный метр остается

Comment: @JohnDoe если "левый" в вашем случае означает "символы, которые MySQL не понимает", то это следует упомянуть в вопросе. MySQL 5.5+ (2009-) поддерживает non-BMP символы, используя подходящую кодировку: utf8mb4, utf16, или utf32 поэтому нет необходимости никакие символы удалять.

Answer (score 0):

Отключите спецсимволы - перед кавычками поставить r.
Или создайте список "левых" символов